# Export custom created admin page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, admin

All right so i have created a page in the wordpress admin called Theme Options.When i export my files the links of these pages are not exported.I want the links that i have included in this page to be also exported using the export plugin.
How can this be done ?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those links stored/retrieved as wordpress options? If so, then just migrating the files will not migrate the database as well.

Regarding Options: http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference

If you aren't storing them there you can just hard code them into the form.

Comment: Hi @xiskus welcome to the forum. How do i hardcode them into the form?

Comment: You can use the placeholder attribute. <input type="text" placeholder="stuff you want to go here"> something like that.